# Autocomplete only on demand in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, autocomplete, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

In Open-/Libreoffice Calc, it is possible to enable the auto-completion of cells. That means the cell is filled e.g. with a string that starts with the characters already typed. This may give unwanted effects so I'd like to disable this option.

Is there (for example) a shortcut that completes the text in the current cell when auto-completion is disabled globally?

Comment: From the Help section: "Automatic Text or Number Completion
When making an entry in a cell, LibreOffice Calc automatically suggests matching input found in the same column. This function is known as AutoInput.
To turn the AutoInput on and off, set or remove the check mark in front of Tools - Cell Contents - AutoInput." But I'm unaware of a way to have it enabled on demand. Let's see if someone knows how to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Almost a solution:
You can map a key to toggle AutoInput. Then you can press that key while entering data, and the next character typed will trigger the completion. Press the mapped key again to turn AutoInput back off. This is much faster than going through the menu each time.

I tried it and it seems to work well enough, although it would be nice to have AutoInput turn off automatically after pressing ‹enter›. Perhaps that would be possible through a macro, but that's not my expertise.

To those needing to know how to map a key:
Tools > Customize > Keyboard
Function > Options > AutoInput
Shortcut keys > scroll and select desired key > Modify

I thought ‹control›‹insert› was logical, and it was previously undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately one can't map Tab this way, which would have been the logical solution. Currently it does nothing while editing cell contents.